# Delete all .psd files in one folder

Tags: perl, directory, delete-file, file-extension, unlink

So I'm new to perl and I have a folder than contains sub folders that also contain subfolders etc. and all throughout this mess of subfolders and subsubfolders are files that say ".psd"

I tried researching how to delete them all and so far this is my best stab (But I'm not sure what it will do and I don't want to end up deleteing every .psd file on my computer)... I only want to delete all .psd files that are in a certain folder on my desktop (or in that folders subfolders etc)

The code so far:
`unlink glob('*.psd');`

Comment: (Again I'm brand new to perl so how do I set which folder I want to be in to delete all those .psd files... Is it just whichever folder I saved the .pl file perlscript document in?)

Answer (score 1):

Script generated and modified in a few seconds with the help of :

```
find2perl -type f -name '*.psd'
```

:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use autodie;  # abort execution with warning when "unlink" fails.
use File::Find;

find {
  # do the "wanted" action for each file/directory
  wanted => sub {
    unlink $_ if -f $_ and /\.psd$/;
    # -f tests that the entry is a normal file
    # The regex /\.psd$/ tests that the filename has a .psd ending
  },
}, $ARGV[0]; # take the start directory from command line
```

Called like

```
$ perl the-script.pl /place/where/you/want/to/start
```

This will work recursively in the desired directory.

Comment: `find2perl` generates horrible code and should not be shown as an example to people new to perl. The `wanted` should look like `unlink $_ if -f $_ and /\.psd$/` with the `no_chdir` option set.

Comment: True that this is ugly, it doesn't pass `perlcritic -4` =) But it works.

Comment: Feel free to modify my post amon.

Comment: @sputnik Ok, I scrubbed the useless parts.